# I need to print the nth element of a list whose name is a variable(inside a foreach block) tcl

Tags: linux, tcl

I have defined a variable having a list of values. I can print this in tclsh with [lindex name index]. But I have a loop in which the iterator is storing the name of the list. I am unable to find out how to solve it. Sample code below:

```
#assuming i have this value stored 
set vsxhi [list 1.2 1.4 ]

#loop starts here
set iterator vsxhi
puts "first element of vsxhi needs to be printed in the loop; Im stuck"
puts [lindex $iterator 0]
puts [lindex $$iterator 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) to get an indirect reference to the list variable:

```
set vsxhi {1.2 1.4}
foreach iterator {vsxhi} {
    upvar 0 $iterator list
    puts [lindex $list 0]
}
```

You could also use [`eval`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/eval.htm), but it's a lot uglier and more error prone:

```
set vsxhi {1.2 1.4}
foreach iterator {vsxhi} {
    puts [eval [format {lindex $%s 0} $iterator]]
}
```

Or of course you could store your lists in an array or dict instead of as independent variables:

```
set lists(vsxhi) {1.2 1.4}
foreach iterator {vsxhi} {
    puts [lindex $lists($iterator) 0]
}
```

This is the least tricky and simplest approach.

And I never remember that `set` can work with a single argument...

```
foreach iterator {vsxhi} {
    puts [lindex [set $iterator] 0]
}
```

which is better than the fancy approaches.

Comment: The other option that you don't mention is single-argument `set` call — it does a read — which might result in a central code snippet like this: `puts [lindex [set $iterator] 0]`